# Not displaying instances of an object if certain attributes are identical to an already displayed instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am grabbing a bunch of properties based on parameters sent from a form, like this:

```
def index
  @properties = Property.all
  @properties = @properties.where("bedrooms = ?", params[:bedrooms]) if params[:bedrooms].present?
  @properties = @properties.text_search(params[:query]) if params[:query].present?
  @properties = @properties.area_search(params[:area]) if params[:area].present?
  @properties = @properties.where("month_available = ?", params[:availability]) if params[:availability].present?
  @properties = @properties.where("vacancy_status = ?", params[:now]) if params[:now].present?
end
```

When I am listing the properties in my view via the `@properties` instance variable and running an each loop, with something like this:

```
<% @properties.each do |property| %>
  <%= property.street_address %>
  <%= property.latitude %>
  <%= property.longitude %>
<% end %>
```

I do not want to show some of the instances of `property` if the `property.latitude && property.longitude` is identical to another instance that has already been shown.  How would I go about doing this?

I am using `Postgres` and the app is `rails 4.0.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try sth like:

```
<% @properties.uniq {|p| [p.latitude, p.longitude]}.each do |property| %>
```